# What kind of lawyer would a witness need to protect themselves

Tags: united-states, witnesses, deposition

My wife used to work for a company 'A'.  Some employees of that company, as well as some state employees are being sued in federal court for civil rights violations (my wife is not named in the suit).  The company is paying for counsel for the defendants that worked for them at the time.  That counsel has reached out to my wife saying that the plaintiff wants to depose her.  There has been no contact between plaintiff's counsel and my wife.  I have concerns about this one sided contact.

My wife feels she did everything right in regards to the matter, and I trust her opinion.  However I'm encouraging her to retain counsel to make sure neither side tries take advantage.  My question is, what kind of lawyer should we be looking for?

My wife has no interest in helping either party beyond the extent required by law and would prefer to not have to testify in person since the trial is currently in a court that is more than 5 hours away from where we live.

Comment: Important detail:  was your wife named in the suit?

Comment: Edited and no, she isn't and I'd like to keep that from happening :)

Comment: Does she have info that could help or harm one of the sides?

Comment: @PeteB. She doesn't remember much but is certain she filled out all of the appropriate documentation of the incident which the defense would have access to.  The existence of said documentation and its contents could potentially be advantageous to the plaintiff

Comment: In what country? Different countries have different subtypes of lawyers.

Comment: The country is USA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

She would want a litigation attorney that specializes in this kind of case. For instance if the underlying issue is an OSHA violation, there may be questions that imply a degree of culpability by the witness, and an attorney who knows that area of law (as opposed to copyright or drug-trafficking) would be in the best position to protect the interests of the witness.